# FindViewById returning null?

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a `listView` from an array. However, when I try and find the listview in my java code, the findViewById function returns null.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/androidbg_dark"
    tools:context=".DiaryActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstAppts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" ></ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="64dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOther"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                android:onClick="newAppointment"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOther2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                android:onClick="newAppointment"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewAppt"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                android:onClick="newAppointment"
                android:text="@string/newappt"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the offending code:

```
ListView lstAppts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAppts);
String[] data = { "Appointment 1", "Appointment 2", "Appointment 3" };

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
lstAppts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To my knowledge, I am referencing the listview correctly. It is named 'lstAppts' in my XML, and in the `findViewById` function, I find it using `R.id.lstAppts`. However when I debug the code with breakpoints, I can clearly see the the lstAppts object is `null`. Why is this?

Comment: with the context you provide is impossible to understand why it is null. Maybe you forgot to call setContentView, for instance

Comment: is the java code in the DiaryActivity class?

Comment: Have you inflated the layout properly at the moment you are calling `findViewById`?

Comment: I think you have `setContentView` loading a different layout.

Comment: Are you calling `findViewById` before you call `setContentView()` ?

Comment: Post logcat error. This is very important in this situation.

Comment: Post complete code ..either you forget to call setcontentview or you forget to call LayoutInflator.inflate

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to call `findViewById()` on constructor. In Android you should use `onCreate()` method to init your Activity instead of constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't inflate the correct layout on the onCreate method. Check the setContentView method and make sure that it match the layout name of your "listView".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using listview in dialog,pop-up, etc where you have a parameter Context context type, you must use findViewById like this.

```
ListView lstAppts = (ListView) context.findViewById(R.id.lstAppts);
```

Or if you have: **View layout**

```
ListView lstAppts = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lstAppts);
```

Cheers,